# Transparent colour of image changes when loading from storage

Tags: android, image, png

I've built some sort of caching system for an Android app. It stores generated images onto the internal storage and then reloads them whenever the app is reopened (to avoid large delays). Now colors of part of the image change when it is loaded from the internal storage compared to regenerating it every time.

Before saving to storage (What it *should* look like):
[image]

After reloading the image from the internal storage:
[image]

The white background circle changes into a black one, but it is still transparent (the red background still shines through). This is the code that I'm using for saving the image to the internal storage:

```
// The format that's used to persistently store all logos in the application.
public static final String IMAGE_FORMAT = "png";
public static final Bitmap.CompressFormat IMAGE_COMPRESS_FORMAT = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG;
// Image quality settings used for storing the logos in the persistent storage.
public static final int IMAGE_QUALITY = 0;

String fileName = "cache/test.png";

FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
output.setHasAlpha(true);
output.compress(Constants.IMAGE_COMPRESS_FORMAT, Constants.IMAGE_QUALITY, fos);
```

And this is the code that I'm using for reloading the image:

```
FileInputStream in = context.openFileInput(fileName)
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
output = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, opts);
```

I've already tried to change the **inPreferredConfig** but has no effect. The code for applying the Bitmap as a Drawable to the ImageView is exactly the same in both situations (same method), that shouldn't be the problem.

I've also tried to use the **setHasAlpha(true)**-method before compressing the Bitmap, but that also does not change anything.

Any ideas on how to fix this weird behavior?

Comment: Have you checked the format of image may be you got the .jpeg file and try to convert it to .png.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I've double checked this and the image is saved as a PNG as can be seen in the sample-code. Thanks for helping me anyway :)

Comment: Try to increase the quality of image as I see in your code quality of image is 0. Try to set it 100 and then try.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I've tried changing the quality to 100, but no difference. I'm starting to think that this might be an issue in Android itself somewhere. I've also tried to use WEBP as the compression standard, but the issue remains exactly the same.